# How to rollback changes on temporary context?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I create a temporaryContext like this:

```
let temporaryContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
temporaryContext.parentContext = Utility.managedObjectContext()
temporaryContext.performBlockAndWait({

    // .. here I have done some changes on temporaryContext

    let success = temporaryContext.save(nil)

    //GUI get updated, GUI use MAIN context 
})
```

I want to roll back changes, so I do this:

```
temporaryContext.performBlockAndWait({                                
    temporaryContext.rollback()
    let success = temporaryContext.save(nil)

    //GUI not get restored to the default variable
})
```

But it has no effect, parent context will not rolled back, why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by " state stick into the changed state". Have you made any changes between first `temporaryContext.save(nil)` call and `temporaryContext.rollback()`? If so, do these changes remain in managed objects after calling `rollback`?

Comment: I haven't do any changes, what I mean, that parent context will not rolled back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `rollback` it only reverts unsaved changes in that context. In the first block of code you have already saved those changes and thus `rollback` will not do anything.

When you called `save` in the first code block all of the changes were committed to the parent context which, I assume, is the main context in this case. Because you have not yet called `save` on the main context you should still be able to call `rollback` on the main context to remove those changes in the main context.